# Book recommendation: Constructing diffeomorphisms / homeomorphisms (elementary differential geometry)

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, soft-question, book-recommendation, diffeomorphism

Sorry for the vague title, i didn't know how to phrase it correctly. I noticed that i have a very hard time whenever it comes to finding explicit diffeomorphisms or homeomorphisms rather than proof by picture or hand waving arguments. I assume that this has also to do with my lack of exposure to elementary geometry courses in the past.

I stumbled upon this question: [How to deal with hoemomorphisms](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/362862/how-to-deal-with-homeomorphisms)

which is essentially exactly what i mean.

However, i figured that this is barely something that can be covered in a single Q&A, thus i wanted to ask if anyone happens to know some good books that would fit my needs.

I really do not know what exactly to look for. Elementary geometry books? Undergraduate level Differential geometry books?

I would really appreciate any recommendation.

Comment: Look for a multivariable calculus book (or several of them) having **lots** of examples and exercises that force you to write down lots of formulas.

Comment: Thank you very much @LeeMosher. I will look for them, can you recommend a specific one?

Comment: No, I have no particular recommendations. Start with the one you learned multivariable calculus from, I suppose.

Comment: Thanks Lee. Highly appreciated.